# appended child elements not displaying using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have done and researched everything but the divs are still not displaying after appending.Chrome console shows no errors. Please help  me.

what is it i'm doing wrong?

```js
var orderlist=document.getElementById("order-list-cont");
window.onload=function() {
 if (menu.x>0){
  for(i = 1; i <= menu.x; ){

   var div=document.createElement("div");
   div.className="col-md-6 col-food";

   var img=document.createElement("img");
   var y='item'+i;
   
   img.src=menu[`${y}`].picture;
   img.className="imag";

   var h6=document.createElement("h6");
   h6.innerHTML=menu[`${y}`].delicacy;

   var input=document.createElement("input");
   input.type="text";
   input.value=1;

   var button=document.createElement("button");
   button.className="btn";
   button.innerHTML="Place Order";

   div.appendChild(img);
   div.appendChild(h6);
   div.appendChild(input);
   div.appendChild(button);
   orderlist.appendChild(div);

   i+=1;
   console.log(y);
  }
 }
};
```

Even the console.log(y) isn't returning any value.

**EDIT**
This is the remaining part of the code above. menu, x and other properties are well defined. Guys,i really appreciate your help.

```js
var add = document.getElementById("add");

var menu={
  x:0,
};

if (add!=null){
add.onclick=function(){
  var x=document.getElementById("DELICACY").value;
  var y=document.getElementById("QUANTITY").value;
  var z=document.getElementById("PRICE").value;
  var u=document.getElementById("PICTURE").value;
  menu.x+=1;
  var k=menu.x;
  var name= "item"+k;
  menu[`${name}`]={"x":k, "delicacy":x, "quantity":y, "price":z, "picture":u};
  console.log(menu);
};
}
```

Comment: What is `menu`?

Comment: That `for` loop will never stop, because you didn't give it an "incrementer". It  should look like this: `for (let i = 1; i <= menu.x; i++) {` (spaces are mostly optional of course)

Comment: Well, check what x is, and if the test is a valid one. It looks like you aren't even entering the branch or loop. Start from the known and work to the unknown. Remember, no one here wants to debug this for you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: [it works in this fiddle using your code and a made-up object](https://jsfiddle.net/zL5gv7L5/1/).

Comment: @Andy yeah, I can't think of anything that would cause no errors besides the loop not executing at all. `menu.x < 1` or `menu.x` being `undefined`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `menu.x` property is not set to something greater than 0.  Instead of using a property on the object, iterate over the object using a `for of` loop.  It would be ideal if the object contains only items you want to display, but there is also a check to make sure that the properties `picture` and `delicacy` are present.

```js
var orderlist = document.getElementById("order-list-cont"),
  menu = {
    item1: {
      picture: 'https://placeimg.com/50/50/any',
      delicacy: 'roses'
    },
    item2: {
      picture: 'https://placeimg.com/50/50/any',
      delicacy: 'fish'
    },
    item3: {},
    item: {},
    otherProp: true
  };

for (let key of Object.keys(menu)) {
  let item = menu[key];
  if (item.picture == null || item.delicacy == null) continue;

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "col-md-6 col-food";

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = item.picture;
  img.className = "imag";

  var h6 = document.createElement("h6");
  h6.innerHTML = item.delicacy;

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.value = 1;

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.className = "btn";
  button.innerHTML = "Place Order";

  div.appendChild(img);
  div.appendChild(h6);
  div.appendChild(input);

  div.appendChild(button);
  orderlist.appendChild(div);
};
```

```html
<div id="order-list-cont"></div>
```